# xtype-datetime Time dropdown is disabled

Tags: aem

I am using the **datetime** widget in one of the AEM components. The date field is working fine, however the time field appears disabled (see snapshot below).

[image]

The field configuration is

```
<startdatetime
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    dateFormat="d/M/Y"
    fieldLabel="Start Date/Time"
    name="./startdatetime"
    xtype="datetime" />
```

Comment: The above configuration is working as expected at my end. Check if there are any listeners that have been registered on the widget. Also list the details of the browser and version of AEM that is being used.

Comment: Its a Simple dialog with only two field start and expire date only no any listeners and any other things

Comment: Issue is on all the browsers or any specific browser?

Comment: No It remain same for all browser

Comment: I think you are missing the property "timeFormat": https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.DateTime